# Subsetting or filtering within dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

There are multiple similar questions on this but not the same problem

MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df= data.frame(id = c(1:5),
               type = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b"),
               start = dmy(c("05/05/2005","06/06/2006", "07/07/2007", "08/08/2008", "09/09/2009")),
               finish = dmy(c("08/08/2008", "09/09/2009","02/02/2011","02/02/2011", NA)),
               not_used = c(F,T,F,T,F))
```

I want to produce a summary, grouped by `type`, including the total number of `not_used` by type and the mean difference between `start` and `finish` in  months when `not_used` is False. This is how I'm trying:

```
df%>%group_by(type)%>%
  summarise(Not_used =  sum(not_used),
            `Mean_Lifespan_of_used(months)` = mean((interval(start,finish)/months(1), na.rm= T)[not_used == F]))
```

With this I'm getting `unexpected token ','`, resulting in error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"  summarise(Not_used =  sum(not_used),
            `Mean_Lifespan_of_used(months)` = mean((interval(start,finish)/months(1),"
```

I appreciate I could create a new column before the summarise function, but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Your `as.Date` needs `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I think the subsetting should be done before applying the `mean` i.e. `mean` returns a single value whereas `not_used` length is different

Comment: your code also shows a `(` which is not closed correctly i.e. `summarise(Not_used =  sum(not_used), `Mean_Lifespan_of_used(months)` = mean((interval(start,finish)/months(1), na.rm= TRUE))` whereas `summarise(Not_used =  sum(not_used), `Mean_Lifespan_of_used(months)` = mean(interval(start,finish)/months(1), na.rm= TRUE)[not_used == FALSE])` returns incorrect output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data `as.Date` needs `format = "%d/%m/%Y"` and then subset the output before doing the `mean` (as `mean` returns a single value whereas `not_used` length is different)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df%>%
   group_by(type)%>%
  summarise(Not_used =  sum(not_used),  
   `Mean_Lifespan_of_used(months)` = mean((interval(start, 
         finish)/months(1))[not_used == FALSE], na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  type  Not_used `Mean_Lifespan_of_used(months)`
  <chr>    <int>                           <dbl>
1 a            1                            39.1
2 b            1                            42.8
```